# When can we say a transaction is committed in mysql?

Tags: mysql, transaction-log, transaction, acid

I know the transaction can ensure that all the queries are committed or rolled back, but what is the point at which we can say ok, the transaction has been committed and all changes are durable?
I think it is **when commit flag is written into redo log** (take mysql as an example), is it right?

Answer (score 1):

For all intense and purposes, the transaction is commit - then `commit` statement is complete. At that point all changes are durable and will survive reboot even if the data is technically still in "dirty pages" and not in the table's pages.

When dirty pages become white? That depends on the RDBMS and each one has a lengthy discussion in documentation about this. For MySQL the rules for this are described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-buffer-pool-flushing.html

Comment: Good answer, but it applies to a single (non-replicated) server.  Old replication is async.  Semi-sync is well,...  Galera involves the gcache.  Etc.  In those situations, then "maybe".

Comment: But there is another problem: when can we say commit statement is complete from mysql server's view? Notice: I know it is hard from client's view, but i think it is a determinate action for server, after executing a certain c++ statement for example.